# How do I handle a message from a user generated combobox in my main window?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I've created a combobox manually in my main window using CreateWindow().  Because of this it has no ID associated with it only the handle returned by CreateWindow().  When the user makes a selection from the combobox list and the combobox throws a message, how do I handle that in the WinProc WM_COMMAND code since there is no ID associated with the combobox? As far as I can tell, I must know the combobox ID to handle the message.  This is especially problematic once I have more than one combobox in the main window.  Surely there is something I am missing and there is a simple answer.

Comment: It does have an ID - whatever you passed for `hMenu` parameter of `CreateWindow`. In any case, `WM_COMMAND` comes with the control's `HWND` in `lParam`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.  So what Igor Tandetnik stated is the answer.

> It does have an ID - whatever you passed for `hMenu` parameter of `CreateWindow`...

This is also discussed in the following link.

[What is winapi HMENU and how do i use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20533217/what-is-winapi-hmenu-and-how-do-i-use-it)

From the above link:

> `HMENU` is a handle to a menu, e.g. as created by `LoadMenu` (which creates a menu from a specification in a resource).

> But, the `CreateWindow` function re-uses the same argument for two different purposes. With a top-level window it's a menu handle, but with a child window it's the child window id, which should be in 16-bit integer range...

> When creating a child window, just cast the id to `HMENU`.